# Am I doing anything wrong in this async example?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm new to asynchronous programming, and I have been working on a small example to demonstrate how to program with tasks. I was wondering about your opinions on the sample.

Am I blocking anywhere? Am I doing anything wrong?
Can it be made better somehow?

Here is the code of the sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string directory= "files";

    IEnumerable<string> files = FindFiles(directory).ToList();

    DateTime startAsink = DateTime.Now;

    ProcessFilesAsync(files).ContinueWith(r =>
    {
        r.Result.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks - startAsink.Ticks);
    });

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> FindFiles(string directoy)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(directory).ToList();
}

private static Task<Tuple<string, int>> ProcessOneFile(string name)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(name);
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (var line in lines )
        {
            sum += line.Split(' ').Length;
        }

        return new Tuple<string, int>(name, sum);
    });
}

    private static async Task<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>>  ProcessFilesAsync(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        var listOfResults = files.Select(ProcessOneFile);

        var task = (await Task.WhenAll(listOfResults)).ToList();

        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ProcessFilesAsync` is async. and you don't await on it. resharper/VS will warn you about it. what you've just  did is Fire and Forget. I don't know what  your needs are but i'm just noticing you. Also. you use `ContinueWith` while you should use `await ( if you're really with async-await approach)

Comment: I use continueWith in the Main method because I don't want the Main method to be marked with async... In the book Writing High-Performance .Net Code, there is a sentence that says that await and wait are similar but different and that everything after the await happens in a continuation... maybe, I'm wrong, but as I understood it isn't quite like blocking... also, I want to return a list of results from the ProcessFilesAsync... btw resharper warns me when I mark method with async but don't use "await"

Comment: Your code seems to take a bunch of filenames, and count how many words there's in each file. The problem is there's nothing async (awaitable) in your code. A least, you can should use TextReader.ReadLineAsync to read lines of your files instead of File.ReadLines..

Comment: If your code works, this might be a better fit for us over on at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Marin: That's a great book as a performance metrics reference, or a how-to guide for tracking down performance problems. But it's not an introduction to async at all. I'd recommend starting with my [async intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: I always recommend @StephenCleary blog post on async/wait and `Task.Run` to everyone who asks about it, so definitely a +1 from me too

Comment: I would think frequent use of ToList() could degrade performance.  I'd suggest you try test performance after removing every instance of ToList().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I blocking anywhere?

No, it seems that your use of the "async all the way" flow is correct. *But*, you are using blocking API's (such as `File.ReadLines`) when you can be using its `async` brother, via `TextReader.ReadLineAsync`.

> Am I doing anything wrong?

Things i can spot immediately is:

1. You use the [async over sync anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). Instead of encapsulating the call to `Task.Run` inside your "async" method, you should expose a synchronous one and let the caller explicitly call `Task.Run`. That way, you're not letting him assume this method is naturally asynchronous when it isn't really.
2. Naming conventions. Any async method should end with the `Async` postfix.

> Can it be made better somehow?

Instead of using `Task.Run` to do IO bound operations, you can use API's that expose naturally async file reading, such as the `FileStream` and `TextReader` classes. That way, you're *really* exposing an `async` method, and not an "async over sync" one.

Comment: He does block (not the main thread) when _File.ReadLines_ as opposed to _file.ReadLineAsync_ IMHO

Comment: @RoyiNamir I ment he's not blocking on any `Task` returning operation. I didn't mean he's not making any *blocking calls*. I'll make that clear. BTW, the `File` utility class has no `ReadLineAsync`, you probably ment the one on the `StreamReader` class.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've actually tried reimplementing the code as Sharped suggested, and I get worse performance (file has around 87 MB) using TextReader.ReadLineAsync... Files.ReadLines returns result immediately, while it took much longer to get the result with ReadLineAsync... NB: the large file has one word per line.

Comment: @Marin `File.ReadLines` uses deferred execution. It will only execute once you start iterating it inside your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I am aware of that, however, from your answer, I was expecting it to be equally fast. From your answer on my question "Can it be made better somehow?" ...

Comment: What i was aiming at isn't Better == Faster. It is more Better == Properly async.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible async refactoring of your code :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string directory = "files";
        IEnumerable<string> files = FindFiles(directory).ToList();
        Stopwatch chrono = new Stopwatch();
        chrono.Start();
        var tasks = files.Select(f => ProcessOneFileAsync(f)).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        chrono.Stop();
        foreach (var t in tasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(chrono.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> FindFiles(string directoy)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(directoy).ToList();
    }

    private static async Task<Tuple<string, int>> ProcessOneFileAsync(string name)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        using (TextReader file = File.OpenText(name))
        {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = await file.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                sum += line.Split(' ').Length;
            }
        }
        return new Tuple<string, int>(name, sum);
    }
```

PS : I replaced `DateTime` by `Stopwatch` for consistent timing results.

Comment: it would   be better to  add PrlocessOneFile``Async`` it's just a naming convention

Answer (score 1):

I see several things wrong with it.  Usually when one is working `async`, its because they want to work with results that trickle in as they become available (think: `yield`) rather than wait for the entire collection to become fully formed.

Every use of `ToList` is a slap in the face of `async` and `yield`.  You are in essence declaring you want your code to wait before progressing.

Consider the use of `GetFiles` in your `FindFiles` method.  If you omit the `ToList`, `GetFiles` returns a `string[]`, which implements `IEnumerable<string>` anyway.  But more importantly, you should completely replace the `GetFiles` with `EnumerateFiles`.  I welcome you to read **MSDN** at your own leisure but I do include this quote:

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

So `FindFiles` becomes:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FindFiles(string directory)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory);
}
```

And you should also remove every reference to `ToList` elsewhere for the same reason.  That's the 2 biggest issues dealing directly with `async`.  That way your code can indeed perform `async` and process items as they become available.

Another thing is that `DateTime.UtcNow` should be used for any internal timings.  Not only is `UtcNow` much faster than the localized `DateTime.Now`, it also is not subject to any quirks from time zone transitions.

Comment: Tnx, will do :) I only used DateTime.Now for measurment (I could have used Stopwatch)